# In React MultiSelect, make at least one selection required using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, react-18

I'm using the MultiSelect component from react-multi-select-component in a React 18 create-react-app application that uses Typescript:

```
import {MultiSelect} from 'react-multi-select-component';
```

And I'm using react-hook-form to validate required fields on form submission:

```
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';
```

I want to force the user to select at least one item from the MultiSelect. Can I do this using react-hook-form? I cannot find any example.

I have my MultiSelect inside a wrapper like so:

```
const MultiSelectWrapper = (props : MultiSelectType) => {
return (
    <MultiSelect
    options={props.options} 
    value={props.value}
    onChange={props.onChange}
    disableSearch={props.disableSearch}
    labelledBy={props.labelledBy}
    className={props.className}
    defaultIsOpen={props.defaultIsOpen}
    />)
;
};
export default MultiSelectWrapper;
```

And I'm rendering it inside the form tag like so:

```
<MultiSelectWrapper disableSearch={true} 
 labelledBy='Policy Types' 
 value={policyTypes}
 options={policyTypeOptions} 
 onChange={setPolicyTypes}
 className="w-72"
 defaultIsOpen={false}/>
```

Getting validation to work for text and select inputs is very easy. For a text input, inside of a regular form tag, I just do this:

```
<input 
 {...register("title", {
      required : "Title is required",
      minLength: {
      value: 1,
      message: "Please enter at least one character for Title."
 }
 })}
 id="title" type="text" 
 value={title} 
 placeholder="Enter title here" 
 className="rounded px-2 py-2 min-w-full" 
 onChange={(e) => {setTitle(e.target.value);}} />
 <span className="text-red-600"> 
 {errors.title?.message}</span>
```

Requiring the user to select an option from a select input it is equally trivial:

```
<select>
{...register("formTypeId", {
    required : "Form Type is required",
    min: {
    value: 1,
    message: "Please select a Form Type."
  }
   })}
   className="px-3 py-3 rounded-full w-60" 
    id="formTypeId" 
  value={formTypeId} 
  onChange={(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setFormTypeId(parseInt(e.target.value));
  }}>
  <option value="0">--Select a Form Type--</option>
  {formTypesData.map((formType: FormTypeType) => <FormType key={formType.formTypeId} formTypeId={formType.formTypeId} description={formType.description}/>)}
  </select>
  <span className="text-red-600">{errors.formTypeId?.message}</span>
```